# What rules for curly braces inside an IF ELSE statement in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, curly-braces

I'm doing a beginners course in C#, trying to understand how to use curly braces inside of IF ELSE statements. I find that if I have one statement in the IF or ELSE body, I don't need curlies, if I have 2 or more statements, then I need curlies. But > NOT ALWAYS!. I'm using Visual Studio, and sometimes it compiles without curlies, and other times I need to put them in. it's maddening.

As you can see here 2 statement lines printed fine on the console.  (ignore the other stuff). No curlies.

[image: 2 statements with no curly braces]

Now here I'm trying to compile the next day and it's requiring the braces (although this is now for the IF part of the IF ELSE, doesn't matter, I had it working yesterday with 2 statements no problems).

[image: IF statement error]

And here with the braces the error disappears.

[image: with curlies]

It's frustrating because sometimes VS requires curlies, other times it does not.

I believed if just one statement in the body I don't need curlies,
If 2 or more statements in the body I need curly braces to show that everything in the braces get executed.

But Visual studio 19 seems to be changing its mind each day.
I must be going mad.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#blocks  *"A block permits multiple statements to be written in contexts where a single statement is allowed."*

Comment: _"its frustrating because sometimes VS requires curlies, other times it does not."_ - C# will always execute the next block after the if statement declaration. In cases where a scope (denoted by curly braces) is present, it will execute everything in that scope. In cases where a line of code is present without curly braces, it will execute everything up to the first `;` and then exit the `if` statement.

Comment: P.S. You should include code as _text_ not as images as your question, though you can also use images to further illustrate your problem.

Comment: Your "2 statements with no curlies" isn't actually 2 statements. Its 1 statement inside the else block, and 1 statement outside. The 2nd print will print no matter what happens with your if statement.

Comment: Code the compiles, is not necessarily correct, or it may work for reasons you do not fully grok. Code that does not compile, is certainly incorrect, even if you do not grok the reason.

Comment: Please do not use a backtick instead of a single apostrophe. It messes up the formatting of your text. They are not the same thing, and are not interchangeable. The single apostrophe is next to the Enter key - use it instead of the backtick that is below the Esc key. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks madreflection!, ok @John thanks for the insight and will do post code next time.  Loocid great! I did experience that yesterday and got confused. thanks for clarifying. jwdonahue well said, noted. Ken White got it thank you!.

Comment: Thanks Olivier for this excellent list.

Answer (score 6):

if you comment line number 31 and 32 it wont give you compile error.

```
//this is correct format.
if(true)
    doX();
else 
    doY();

//this is not.

if(true)
    doX();
Console.WriteLine(); <- this is not part of if statement. 
else doY();
```

here Console.WriteLine() is considered as an independent statement. Hence 'if' for the else is lost.

When you put curly braces it considers as a single block -

```
//this is correct format.

if(true)
{
    doX();
    Console.WriteLine();  
}
else doY();
```

Comment: fantastic thanks chaitali!

Answer (score 3):

In C# you're not allowed to put two independant lines of code in the same indentation or even after one another after an `If` statement, when it's followed by an else, without using curly brackets.

An `Else` statement can't be used without an `if` statement, so when you type an `if` statement (without curly brackets) followed by two lines of code, followed by an `else` statement. The compiler will run the `if` statement and the following code inside the clause if it is true, otherwise it will expect to see an `else`, `else if` statement or another line of code, if there is no other statements, then it won't expect to find any statements. So when it fires a line of code and proceeds to see a single `else` statement it will complain, since an else can't start a statement.

And that's why it says `Else` cannot start a statement.

It's a lot to get used to, but once you do, it will come naturally.

Comment: For the record, indentation or any sort of white spacing don't matter in c#.

Comment: You are absolutly right. Am kinda tired, tried to explain it in one way or another. For the record try saying that to a perfectionist lol.